# Adding 1 day from the current date in liquibase property

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I need to insert a date by adding 1 day to the current date using Liquibase.
I'm using Liquibase property for this. But it is always inserting the current date.

Following is the property I'm using

```
<property name="now" value="now() + interval 1 day" dbms="mysql" />
```

I also tried

```
<property name="now" value="now() + interval '1 day'" dbms="mysql" />
```

didn't work either.

In my changeset I've the insert script

```
<insert tableName="test">
            
     <column name="start_date" value="${now}"/>
          
</insert>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
<property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql" />
```

In changeSet

```
<insert tableName="test">
      <column name="start_date" valueComputed="DATE_ADD(${now}, INTERVAL 1 DAY)"/>
</insert>
```